# output is shown while breakpoint otherwise not?

Tags: .net, winforms

```
 public void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
        RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
        foreach (Keyword k4 in keywords)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle(100, k4.nodeno * 32, 10,    10));
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (edge e4 in eds)
        {
            if (e4.start + 1 == e4.end)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, 100 + 4, e4.start * 32 + 10, 100 + 4, e4.end * 32);
                g.DrawLine(p, 100 + 8, e4.end * 32 - 8, 100 + 4, e4.end * 32);
                g.DrawLine(p, 100, e4.end * 32 - 8, 100 + 4, e4.end * 32);
            }
            else
            {
                int a = e4.start - e4.end;
                if (a < 0)
                {
                    a = -a;
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100 + 10, e4.start * 32 + 5, 150 + 5 + i, e4.start * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 150 + 5 + i, e4.start * 32 + 5, 150 + 5 + i, e4.end * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 150 + 5 + i, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100 + 10, e4.end * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100 + 10, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100 + 15, e4.end * 32);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100 + 10, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100 + 15, e4.end * 32 + 10);
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100, e4.start * 32 + 5, 50 - 5 - i, e4.start * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 50 - 5 - i, e4.start * 32 + 5, 50 - 5 - i, e4.end * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 50 - 5 - i, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100, e4.end * 32 + 5);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100 - 5, e4.end * 32);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 100, e4.end * 32 + 5, 100 - 5, e4.end * 32 + 10);
                }
                i = i + 10;
            }
        }
        p.Dispose();
    }
```

this function is working when i put a breakpoint in this function otherwise it is not showing the output of this function?...where is the problem i can't understand..?pls help with some idea or solution?

Comment: See if you get it working by calling Form.Invalidate every few seconds(only to test the hypothesis). In that case a breakpoint in VS is causing your form to retdraw or Invalidate, This event handler is not being run (or event is not raised) without breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guess: you're having a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between the *paint* method and code which is supposed to populate *keywords* and *eds* collections. In other words paint is called before you have something inserted into these collections. When stepping through the code under debugger your collections loading routine have enough time to finish what it's supposed to be doing before foreach cycles kick in.

This is just a guess, you need to provide more of your code if you would want to have more intelligent answer.